# How to integrate braintree for get the card nonce in react-native?

Tags: react-native, braintree

I am working on the latest React-native app. I have tried to integrate Braintree to get card nonce using this library. This library is very old and has no errors and responses I got it.

**Library link:** [react-native-braintree-xplat](https://github.com/kraffslol/react-native-braintree-xplat)

**I have attached the my code, here:**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import BTClient from 'react-native-braintree-xplat';

class paymentMethod extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    let token = 'braintree_tokenization_key';
    BTClient.setup(token);
  }

  getCardToken(){
    const card = {
        number: '4111111111111111',
        expirationDate: '10/2023',
        cvv: '123',
    }
    BTClient.getCardNonce(card).then(function (nonce) {
        console.log(nonce, 'nonce');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err, 'err');
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <Button onPress={()=>getCardToken()} > Card Token </Button>
    )
  }
}

export default paymentMethod;
```

Tell me, How to integrate the braintree for get the card nonce?